# How to loop through months of a PHP DatePeriod class?

Tags: php, datetime

I need to get all the numeric months spanned by a date range. So for a range 18 Jul 2014 - 4 Sep 2014, give me 7,8,9.

This is getting me close:

```
$start = new DateTime('2014-07-18');
$interval = new DateInterval('P1M');
$end = new DateTime('2014-09-04');
$period = new DatePeriod($start, $interval, $end);

foreach ($period as $dt) {
    echo $dt->format('n') . PHP_EOL;
}
```

It returns 7 and 8, but no 9 for September because it's not a full P1M interval. I'd like to get 7,8,9 regardless of where the start/end days fall in the month.

Am I going in the right direction?

Comment: You could force your $start date day to be 1, and the $end date day to be 28 (so it is valid for every month). Maybe not super clean but should do the trick.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Found an answer on this page: http://forums.phpfreaks.com/topic/275341-find-what-months-a-date-range-covers/

```
$start = new DateTime('2014-07-18');
$end = new DateTime('2014-09-04');

$inc = DateInterval::createFromDateString('first day of next month');
$end->modify('+1 day');

$p = new DatePeriod($start,$inc,$end);

foreach ($p as $d)
 echo $d->format('n') . PHP_EOL;
```

Outputs:

```
7 8 9
```

Comment: Thanks for this. There's a slight discrepancy if the end date is the last day of the month (01-Jul to 30-Sep results in 7,8,9,10) but I can live with that.

Comment: Strange, when I use '2014-07-18', and '2014-09-30' I still get '7 8 9'. Even when I use '2014-07-18', and '2014-08-31' I get '7 8'.